# Android : How to write text to specific area in an image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-image

I am creating an Imagebutton which displays notification number.  Here is my sample image:

[image: Icon Image]

My goal is to write a number (1,2..) on specific black circle in an image.  I tried RelativeLayout and FrameLayout but don't think it is a reliable way to achieve the result.  The reason being Margins, Padding will vary on different device sizes.

Any suggestions to get started?

Comment: Separate the black circle & the pencil background image. Use FrameLayout to position the black circle on top of pencil background. Also, use the circle as a background drawable to a TextView.

Comment: @nitesh Not sure what do you mean by image?  It is there in my question.

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for, but wouldn't it be better if you use a set of images with numbers 1,2..9,9+ ? Going to double digits wouldn't look as good.

Comment: @Signcodeindie where's u r image ? :)

Comment: @JoelFernandes I think i get you but not completely. How can i position the circle background exactly as shown in the image?

Comment: @Signcodeindie Let me try and help you with that. Give me sometime.

Comment: That's a wise idea.  I will have to check with my UX designer if they are ok with upto 9 notifications. This indeed could be the easiest solution :)

Comment: @Signcodeindie I have posted the code below. Peace!

Comment: @Dan It's not an efficient approach.

Comment: **Fun fact:** In the Google Chrome for Android app the tab counter goes from `99` to `:D`, yep that's right a smiley face. Anyway your answer should have been a comment though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/pencil">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/circle"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Images: [image]
[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! One thing i am still doubtful is you used a margin value of 8 dp to get it right, on my eclipse i used a value of 10 to achieve desired result.

android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

Comment: It could be because of the width and height of the circle image. However, you can test it on various screens and see if it's working fine or not.

Comment: Hey Joel, thanks for really making it easy and solving the problem. You deserve a Mark as answer.  Cheers!

Comment: @Signcodeindie I'm glad that my answer was helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom View class which extends from ImageView. You'll have to override the onDraw method and do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // Calculate x and y positions and set up a Paint instance with correct color/size
    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(myNumber), x, y, myPaint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Textview with bacground set as the image

`<TextView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="45sp"
    android:layout_height="45sp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="r"
    />`
Use the gravity to align your text inside the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/text"
    android:text="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code    
Bitmap bitmap = ... // Load your bitmap here
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint(); 
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
paint.setTextSize(10); 
canvas.drawText("Some Text here", x, y, paint);
```

Comment: How to find x,y in my case?

Comment: @Signcodeindie: Please try this coordinates '11,16'